# Conda: How to prevent mkl to openblas switch

Tags: anaconda, conda

Conda wants to downgrade my blas, lapack etc. packages from an mkl to an openblas version. I understand that conda juggling with mkl versus openblas seems not an uncommon issue. Yet, I have not found a solution to do the job for me. I have these packages installed

```
blas                      2.113                       mkl    conda-forge
blas-devel                3.9.0            13_linux64_mkl    conda-forge
libblas                   3.9.0            13_linux64_mkl    conda-forge
libcblas                  3.9.0            13_linux64_mkl    conda-forge
liblapack                 3.9.0            13_linux64_mkl    conda-forge
liblapacke                3.9.0            13_linux64_mkl    conda-forge
mkl                       2022.0.1           h06a4308_117  
mkl-devel                 2022.0.1           h66538d2_117  
mkl-include               2022.0.1           h06a4308_117  
mkl-service               2.4.0            py39h404a4ab_0    conda-forge
mkl_fft                   1.3.1            py39h6964271_2    conda-forge
mkl_random                1.2.2            py39h8b66066_1    conda-forge
```

and I have a `.condarc` (on linux) containing

```
channels:
  - conda-forge
  - defaults
dependencies:
  - python>=3.6
  - numpy>=1.13
  - scipy>=0.18
  - cython>=0.29
  - mkl
  - mkl-devel
  - libblas=*=*mkl
  - bottleneck
  - pip
  - setuptools>=30.3.0
  - h5py
  - pyyaml
  - pytest

ssl_verify: true
auto_activate_base: false
```

Moreover in the `conda-meta` directories I have a `pinned` file, containing the line `libblas=*=*mkl`. Yet, upon `conda update --all` this is suggested:

```
The following packages will be DOWNGRADED:
  ... other pkgs ...
  libblas                              3.9.0-13_linux64_mkl --> 3.9.0-13_linux64_openblas
  libcblas                             3.9.0-13_linux64_mkl --> 3.9.0-13_linux64_openblas
  liblapack                            3.9.0-13_linux64_mkl --> 3.9.0-13_linux64_openblas
```

Why, despite of the the `.condarc` and `pinned` files, am I getting this switch from mkl to openblas, and what else can I do to prevent it?

Comment: The [mutex metapackage](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/concepts/packages.html#mutex-metapackages) is `blas` not `libblas`, so try `blas=*=*mkl` instead.

Comment: `blas=*=*mkl` did the job for me. Btw.: It seems that only the entry in `.condarc` is relevant, while that in `pinned` has no effect. Why? Great link to this mutex metapackage page.

Comment: I need to withdraw my enthusiastic statement: `blas=*=*mkl` does *not* help. In fact, during all my previous attempts to stop conda from swapping from mkl to blas I had commented the `-default` channel off from my `.condarc`. I.e. the listing in my post is wrong. On the system I had `# -default`. Once the `-default` channel is allowed back in, the system restarts to suggest the downgrade to openblas. Any other suggestion?

Comment: I've actually never seen one use `.condarc` like that - I was under the impress Conda only parses keys that are in `conda config --show`. Not sure why pinning isn't working. Another thing to try is `conda install --update-specs blas=*=*mkl*`. That would make sure it is part of the explicit specifications.

Answer (score 5):

See the note section at the end of https://conda-forge.org/docs/maintainer/knowledge_base.html#switching-blas-implementation

> If you want to commit to a specific blas implementation, you can prevent conda from switching back by pinning the blas implementation in your environment. To commit to mkl, add `blas=*=mkl` to `<conda-root>/envs/<env-name>/conda-meta/pinned`, as described in the conda-docs.

Answer (score 1):

I'm posting a quirky workaround for my own OP. This finally worked for me.

**First**, I could **not** convince `conda` to respect the channel ordering in `.condarc` nor the content in the `pinned` files **before** running the update by any other suggestion, including those found outside of *stackoverflow* .

**Second**, I stored a `conda list | grep mkl`, a `conda list | grep intel`, and a  `conda list | grep open` away for later reference. Then I "gave in" and let the "upgrade" happen, running `conda update --all`. No need to mention that after that, my environment indeed showed the unwanted replacement of all `mkl`-type libraries with `openblas` stuff.

**Third**, and within the `openblas`-infested environment I "re-installed" `mkl`

```
    conda install blas=*=*mkl
    conda install libblas=*=*mkl
    conda update numpy
    conda update scipy
    conda install intel-openmp   # the "update" had also removed this ...
```

Also make sure that no `openblas`-stuff remains by doing a `conda remove` on whatever related package. (I'm not claiming that really all of the above commands are necessary to reach the original state of the environment regarding `mkl`.  But that's what I did.)

**Fourth**, comparing with the reference notes from the preceding **second** step I checked that at this point my environment claimed to be back to "all-mkl". Moreover, using this extremely helpful site http://markus-beuckelmann.de/blog/boosting-numpy-blas.html  I also checked, that this was indeed true regarding typical `mkl` timings to be expected.

**On the side**, there is a really weird and confusing issue, which may not be related to the OP but which I stumbled across in this context: On the `WWW` one finds many many many quotes stating, that for `numpy` or `scipy` actually "using" `mkl`, one has to have this kind of output

```
    In []: numpy.show_config()
    blas_mkl_info:
        libraries = ['mkl_rt', 'pthread']
        library_dirs = ['/home/abcd/efgh..../lib']
```

from `numpy/scipy.show_confi()`.  This seems **not true** in general. In fact when one gets

```
    In []: numpy.show_config()
    blas_info:
        libraries = ['cblas', 'blas', 'cblas', 'blas']
        library_dirs = ['/home/abcd/efgh..../lib']
```

this is no cause for panic as long as in `/home/abcd/efgh..../lib` one finds everything linked as

```
    liblapacke.so -> libmkl_rt.so.2*
    libblas.so -> libmkl_rt.so.2*
    ...a.s.o.
```

which I do.

(`conda` is just soo painful. sigh)

Answer (score 0):

The package management can be a mess whenever the Intel MKL package has been updated, but the numpy package has not.  I may end up with Intel MKL being installed, but numpy is using the openblas.  To get this working in my setup, I often do this when creating a new environment:

```
conda create  -y --name test python=3 numpy mkl cmake blas=*=*mkl
```

so that the MKL is installed at the same time as numpy, and numpy will use the MKL.  This often results in an older version of MKL, since numpy was linked against an older version of the MKL.

Without the `blas=*=*mkl`, I will often end up with an openblas based numpy installed with the newest version of the Intel MKL not being used by anything.

```
conda create -n test33 numpy mkl blas=*=*mkl
.
.
.
The following NEW packages will be INSTALLED:

  blas               pkgs/main/osx-64::blas-1.0-mkl
.
  numpy              pkgs/main/osx-64::numpy-1.21.5-py39h2e5f0a9_1
.
  mkl                pkgs/main/osx-64::mkl-2021.4.0-hecd8cb5_637
.

# results in:
blas_opt_info:
    libraries = ['mkl_rt', 'pthread']
```

```
conda create -n test33 numpy mkl
.
.
.
The following NEW packages will be INSTALLED:

  blas               pkgs/main/osx-64::blas-1.0-openblas
.
  numpy              pkgs/main/osx-64::numpy-1.21.5-py39h9c3cb84_1
.
  mkl                pkgs/main/osx-64::mkl-2022.0.0-hecd8cb5_105
.

# results in:
blas_opt_info:
    libraries = ['openblas', 'openblas']
```

Unfortunately, numpy does not appear to show the blas library it is linked against in its version id.  Oftentimes, you will end up with both openblas and mkl in your environment.